# Impact of multi-word instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, instructions

What would be the impact on fetch and decode instructions if instead of encoding one word in an instruction, there were multiple words being encoded?

I know that if instead the words were encoding 64 bits, 128 bits, that the decode and fetch instructions would be slowed down. I think of another impact that this would have though.

Comment: That strongly depends on how you construct your CPU.  I don't think a general answer can be given to that question.  Perhaps try to narrow it down to a concrete CPU design.

Comment: Related: https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=421 has design discussion about paper architecture for high performance.  A variable-length encoding was proposed where instruction-length can be determined efficiently (from the first byte of the instruction), and instruction lengths are multiples of 32-bit chunks.  64-bit fixed-size instructions would be very inefficient.  Also suggested was packing 2 simple operations into one instruction word, gaining some of the benefits of something like ARM's Thumb2 instruction set but biased more towards high performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes variable-length instructions that are multiples of 16-bit chunks are best IMHO. RISC-V, Thumb2, RXv2, Android's Dalvik VM... all use that format

Comment: @phuclv: yeah, that seems likely to me, too.  As long as it's easy to find the length of the whole instruction from the first byte or 16-bit chunk, a decoding stage shouldn't be a big problem and probably doesn't require a decoded-uop cache. Building data caches with efficient unaligned loads is apparently possible, so efficient instruction caches that can fetch larger (32-byte) blocks of instructions on a 16-byte boundary shouldn't be too bad. But note that AArch64 only has a 32-bit instruction format, when they could have redesigned from near scratch for a high-performance variable-len ISA.

Comment: I haven't looked at AArch32 vs. AArch64 machine code enough to know if they can share many decoder transistors or of that was a design consideration the way it was for x86-64.